# ngClass - apply multiple classes from variables?

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm trying to apply multiple classes through ngClass. No conditions.
I have 2 variables that is a string of the class name.

Passing in one variable is easy enough

```
[ngClass]='variable1?.font'
```

I tried passing in these classes by using an array since that is how you would do it if you were passing in the class name as strings

```
[ngClass]="['btn', 'btn-primary']"
```

But passing in variables it doesn't work.

```
<button
   [ngClass]='[variable1?.font, variable2?.color]'
>
```

I've seen examples online of passing in multiple classes but they all involve including conditions.

```
[ngClass]="{ btn:true, 'btn-primary':true }"
```

I'm trying not to include conditions. Not even sure the above code would work since the code might think that it is a IF-Else statement.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Thanks.

Comment: this can fix your problem `<button [ngClass]='[variable1?.font || '' , variable2?.color || '']'>`  check the demo

Comment: Why not use ngStyle? https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the array of classes in the ts file, and any change on the array will reflect to the **ngClass**

```
classesList =[]

ngOnInit() {
 this.classesList.push(variable1.font);
 this.classesList.push(variable1.color);

 setTimeout(() =>{
  this.classesList.push('font-bold')
 },2500);

}
```

template

```
<button [ngClass]='classesList'>
```

> you need to make sure don't push any null value to the array that why your example was not working so make sure you push a string value

so this can fix your problem

```
<button [ngClass]='[variable1?.font || '' , variable2?.color || '']'>
```

another option is create a string values instead of array

```
<button [ngClass]='variable1?.font+ ' '+ variable2?.color'>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-ngclass)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.